# Issue in Custom Date Picker control using Windows Phone toolkit DatePicker control

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have designed a custom datepicker control using `Toolkit Datepicker Control`.

I have a requirement now:

I want to set the display `date start` and `displayenddate`  in the control ,but i could not able to find no  properties to input such date time ranges in toolkit date picker,

Could anyone have idea of how to implement this in my custom control?